# Connected unipotent groups acting on an affine variety (re: stabilizers)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, centralisers

Let $U$ be a connected unipotent algebraic group over a field of characteristic $p>0$. Assume $U$ acts on an affine variety $X$ by regular maps.

Is it true that the stabilizers of rational points $x\in X$ under this action are connected?

**Edit** as the comments below point out, the answer is apparently- no, with an abundance of counterexamples.

---

**Some comments** The question obviously has a positive answer in the case of characteristic $0$ (since the stabilizer is also unipotent alg. gp.). Also, in the case where $X$ is a vector space and $U$ acts on $X$ by linear transformations, one can also show that all stabilizer in $U$ are connected. Lastly, if $p$ is large enough so that the exponential map is defined on $U$, it seems plausible that one can apply it in order to obtain that the stabilizer of elements in $X$ are connected. However, this is an assumption I would avoid if possible.

I think I have an argument for the general case. However, the argument seems to be rather elaborate, and I'm not completely confident that I haven't missed anything, so I thought it might be wise to ask if anyone here is aware of a counter example, or a reference to the proof.

**One last comment** while I cannot assume that $p$ is larger than some huge number (therefore, I wish to avoid applying the exponential map), it is possible to omit 'small' subsets of primes. In particular, it is possible to assume $p$ is 'good' in some sense.

Thank you!

Comment: By "centralizers of rational points", do you mean "stablizers of rational points" (perhaps you mean centralizers of stabilizer subgroups)?  With regard to connectedness of stabilizer,  consider the action of the additive group $\mathbb{G}_a = \text{Spec}\ k[t]$ on itself as follows, $$\mu:\mathbb{G}_a\times \mathbb{G}_a\to \mathbb{G}_a, \ \ \mu^*t = (t^p-t)\otimes 1 + 1\otimes t.$$

Comment: "centralizer"? do you mean stabilizers? If $G\neq 1$ is unipotent and connected, what about $G$ acting on $G/H$, with $H$ a nontrivial finite subgroup?

Comment: Regard $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})_k$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb{G}_a$ and let $Q$ be the quotient (also isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_a$). When we let $\mathbb{G}_a$ act on $Q$, the isotropy groups are nonconnected.

Comment: Thank you, I meant stabilizer. 
I guess your comments more or less say that my argument is invalid. I tried constructing such examples, but missed them somehow. Thanks!